# Jquery Mobile 1.4 rc 1 SVG Icons

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, svg, base64

I'm just starting to work with JQM 1.4 rc 1 to update an existing project with the new framework. Everything was pretty simple...until I got to the icons. Now I understand they switched to SVG icons for their benefits of scaling and such, but now if I want to change the color of the icon, I have to work with this.

```
.ui-icon-arrow-d-l: after {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;
    charset=US-ASCII, %3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22iso-8859-1%22%3F%3E%3C!DOCTYPE%20svg%20PUBLIC%20%22-%2F%2FW3C%2F%2FDTD%20SVG%201.1%2F%2FEN%22%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FGraphics%2FSVG%2F1.1%2FDTD%2Fsvg11.dtd%22%3E%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22Layer_1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20%20width%3D%2214px%22%20height%3D%2214px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2014%2014%22%20style%3D%22enable-background%3Anew%200%200%2014%2014%3B%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%3Cpolygon%20fill%3D%22%23FFF%22%20points%3D%2214%2C3%2011%2C0%203.5%2C7.5%200%2C4%200%2C14%2010%2C14%206.5%2C10.5%20%22%2F%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E');
}
```

Now correct me if I'm wrong but this is base64 encoding? So if I wanted to change the fill color of the svgs, I first have to convert this back to svg? [Mobile Fish](http://www.mobilefish.com/services/base64/base64.php) has a base64 decoder but it returns errors when I enter the code. So is this not base64 and if it not, how to get this back to workable SVG syntax?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/LeGkm/ hover mouse over buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that isn't base64 encoded as you already noticed. It's the SVG source-code run through `escape()`. Running it through [`unescape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FAPI%2FWindow.unescape) will give you the original source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"  width="14px" height="14px" viewBox="0 0 14 14" style="enable-background:new 0 0 14 14;" xml:space="preserve"><polygon fill="#FFF" points="14,3 11,0 3.5,7.5 0,4 0,14 10,14 6.5,10.5 "/><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g></svg>
```

This should be much easier to read and understand.